# Retract solution (WSP) in Visual Studio 2013 - Delete Content Types

Tags: content-type, solution-package, visual-studio-2013

When I use Retract command in VS 2013 on my WSP, content types do not get deleted on the site. So whenever I want to update content types, I need to recreate the site. I've done some analysis on this issue: http://slavensemper.blogspot.com/2014/10/visual-studio-2013-cannot-deploy.html

Since I didn't find any similar issue on the forums, my question is: how do you tackle this issue?

**EDIT:**

Installing Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 - **November 2014 Update** did **NOT** resolve the issue.

Installing Visual Studio 2013 **Update 4** did **NOT** resolve the issue either.

Did anyone try to install Visual Studio Update 5 CTP3: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx? Can you deploy content types with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you do retract on Visual Studio it deactivates features first. If your content type is already being used in some library or list, this content type will not be deleted. First of all you should delete every list with this content type, even from the site collection recycle bin ([IMPORTANT!](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49358/removing-content-type-already-in-use-even-if-removed-from-all-lists)). After this you should successfully retract you solution with content types.

Also, you can make sure where this content type is beeing used with PowerShell script using `SPContentTypeUsage` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeusage.getusages(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: That's all fine, but why does it work in VS2012 normally? Ie, I don't have to delete any lists prior to deployment, VS2012 takes care of that for me.

Comment: In the end I use the same procedure as you described. Here it is described in bullet list style: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/34520/33924